# . Rk domain registration

Tags: domains, domain-registrar

Anybody knows where I can get .rk domains? Looks like nowhere so far - any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember reading once on ICANN's website that "custom" domain registrations are not yet finalized and cannot be bought until some time this summer.

Answer (score 0):

After a quick Google search, it appears to me that there is no such thing as a .rk domain. You may have to go to one of those "custom" domains registrations, but it would cost a LOT likely.

Edit: Revised in comments.

Comment: @Simon thanks ! let's assume, I will go ahead and spend a lot on this. where can I find those "custom" domains registrations?

Comment: Actually, i was wrong. I originally thought of the infamous nyan.cat domain, but .cat is a real one. To get a .whatever it has to go through courts and such, until its passed as a real domain. Essentially: You get to apply to the worlds governments for a few years to get your domain name done. So, my best suggestion is finding a new one to use, since this doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, .rk is not a TLD that is offered anywhere. You can view the list of domain extensions available here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains

Applying for a .rk extension isn't a worthwhile endeavour either. It costs around 185,000 USD and is up for delegation with ICANN.

Where you planning on using it for domain hacking? Something like fo.rk or spa.rk?  Currently the .r* domain extensions available are:
.re
.ro
.rs
.ru
.rw

Maybe something will fit. Otherwise, if might be best to think of another name for your site.

**Note:** Creating your own TLD will take LOTS of money and the capacity to create and manage your own server.